# filter foreach in laravel project

Tags: laravel, foreach, filter, location, distance

currently I am working on a platform for second hand products and I'm working with laravel.

I want to display only products who are max. 10km away from the current user.
User location and Product location are stored in the database and I calculate the distance between them in the same controller that sends the products to the view.

Now i wonder if I can somehow filter my foreach on the distance that is calculated in this controller so that i can filter out the products where the distance is more than 10km.

I feel that my code isn't that good so i'm open to consider other options to achieve this.

Controller function:

```
 public function getNearest()
    {
        $products= Product::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);

        foreach($products as $product) {

    //function that calculate distance
        $user = Auth::user();
        $address = $product->locatie;   //location of product
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        $address2 = $user->locatie; //location current user
        $prepAddr2 = str_replace(' ','+',$address2);
        $geocode2=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr2.'&sensor=false');
        $output2= json_decode($geocode2);
        $latitude2 = $output2->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude2 = $output2->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;


        $coordinate1 = new Coordinate($latitude, $longitude); //location current user
        $coordinate2 = new Coordinate($latitude2, $longitude2); //location product

        $calculator = new Vincenty();
        $d = $calculator->getDistance($coordinate1, $coordinate2);
        $distance =$d/1000;

                $product->distance = round($distance);

        if($product->distance>10){
           //dont show product above 10km and filter foreach somehow?
        }
        }


        return view('welcome',compact('products'));
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="col-lg-3 margin-tb">
        <img src="/uploads/products/{{ $product->afbeelding }}">
        <p>{{ $product->name}}</p>
        <p>{{ $product->details}}</p>
        <p>{{ $product->price}}</p>
         <p>{{ $product->locatie}}</p>
        <p>{{ $product->distance}} km van jouw locatie</p>




        <a href="/Zoekertjes/{{ $product->id }}">bekijken</a>

    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most optimum solution but it should work:

```
public function getNearest()
    {
        $products= Product::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $address2 = $user->locatie; //location current user
        $prepAddr2 = str_replace(' ','+',$address2);
        $geocode2=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr2.'&sensor=false');
        $output2= json_decode($geocode2);
        $latitude2 = $output2->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude2 = $output2->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        $coordinate2 = new Coordinate($latitude2, $longitude2); //location user

        $products->reject(function($product, $key) use($coordinate2) {

    //function that calculate distance

        $address = $product->locatie;   //location of product
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        $coordinate1 = new Coordinate($latitude, $longitude); 
        //location product

        $calculator = new Vincenty();
        $d = round($calculator->getDistance($coordinate1, $coordinate2) / 1000);

        return $d > 10;
        });


        return view('welcome',compact('products'));
    }
```

Why I say it's not optimum is that you're not guaranteed to receive 5 results (pagination doesnt work). That's because you have the distance logic at the php level instead of the database level. One way to fix this is to count the products and if they're < 5, fetch a few more results and calculate distance and if they're > 5, take the first 5.

Of course, the best way would be to handle the distance calculation at the DB level